# Method drag_and_drop_by don't works

Tags: selenium, watir

When I use the method element.drag_and_drop_by(527, 296), the Watir try to drop element in position of mouse rather than the position in method. How works this method and how I can to resolve my problem?

Comment: What browser? Are you getting the same results in both Chrome & Firefox?

Comment: Chrome, but I tried with Firefox too. Same results

Comment: I'm using de watir version 6.16.5 and ruby 2.5.3